# Record a cell and copy data to cell in the same row when column matches todays date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title suggests I have a cell (B3) that updates it's value hourly. At a certain time each day, let's say 10pm, I'd like a script to run automatically that copies the value (x) from this cell to a cell in the same row, that matches the column headed with today's date.

Here is the example image

[image]

today = 26.8.21 (d,m,y :australia)

Here is where I am at so far:

```
// Record history from a cell and append to next available row
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheetoffruit");
   // set today's date
  var Date = sheet.getRange("J1").setValue(new Date());
   // look up date range
  var daterange = sheet.getRange("C1:1");
  // find the column position of today's date
   if (date = daterange) {
   var col = daterange.getColumn(); }
   var value = sheet.getRange("B55").getValue();
   var row = 55;
   sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue(value); 
}
```

I have previously been able to post the value of the ("b55") cell (not in this example) however, I cannot get it to match with the column with today's date.

Comment: have you used new Date function to get today and then formatted to only include the dd.mm.yy in your data? Is the column holding your date type string or date? Is it formatted?

Comment: G'day aNewb, thanks for answering.

Great question. The "new date" function value was not formatted in the cell to be just dd.mm.yy, it also contained time. I formatted to just dd/mm/yy and still ran into this error: " "Exception: The parameters (number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange." . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This function write the xtra fruit value in the column with todays data in row 1 and the last line of the data set.

```
function recordValue() {
   let col = {}
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheetoffruit");
   const dhA = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
   dhA.forEach((h,i) => {col[h] = i+1});
   let xf = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),2).getValue();
   sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),col[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MMM-yyyy")]).setValue(xf);
  
}
```

You can run the function from a timebased trigger but make sure you pick a time the ends up in the correct date.  Because the col object and dts determine where the column is based upon matching with the strings in row 1.

After you explain how to determine the row then we can try the below function to see what going wrong with the col object which determines which column to write into.

Comment: G'day Cooper, thanks for your response.

I am getting this error when I try to run the script: 
 
"Exception: The parameters (number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange."

Additionally, I should have been more clear. In the spreadsheet that I will be actually running this script the "extra fruit" value, wont actually be the lastrow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay how do I determine what row it will be on?

Comment: Presumably the date headers are actually in row 1.

Comment: G'day Cooper, thanks again for your responses. Yes the dates headers are all in row 1.  As for which row it will be on, I have predetermined row(s) that are constant if that's what you mean? E.g. each row has a header. How I go about actually getting the row, I am not sure. Is there a function such as "get.lastrow(-7)" or something similar? Please excuse my limited understanding. Cheers

Comment: It seems that your actually needs differ significantly from the requirements posted in the question.  I suggest asking another question and supply example images and explanations of the actual needs because I'm not interested in playing this silly game with you.